# How can angular project run another angular project?

Tags: angular

I have two angular 12 project that let's say project A and B and both of them was compiled.
Now I want to project A hosts project B. **It means project A should start and run project B.**

In the other hands, project A is a CMS project that must run other compiled angular project dynamicly. 
Is there anyway to do it ?

Comment: Maybe [Module Federation](https://www.angulararchitects.io/en/aktuelles/the-microfrontend-revolution-part-2-module-federation-with-angular/) could help you with this: "*With Module Federation we can use Angular and its router to lazy load separately compiled and deployed microfrontends.*"

Comment: Thank you very much @BizzyBob . I will check it in these days

Comment: Thanks a lot @BizzyBob . It worked very good and solved our problem.. Please write your comment as a answer of question